# Text box not showing Red Validation Error in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

We are currently writing a GUI application using WPF and .Net4.5.

One of our pages contains a `TabControl` with custom `UserControl`s as `TabItem`s. These `UserControl`s just contain a list of editable `TextBox`es.  The `Textbox`es have a custom `ValidationRule` that validates the text based on a regular expression. The issue is that these editable text boxes are bound to `Properties` that get loaded at startup with default values from a text file/database.

I need validation to occur before a text box has focus, or before it is edited, to ensure that the values that were entered in the text file/database were  entered correctly. Currently, when I select a tab item the text boxes are not displaying the red validation error box, even though it seems validation is running correctly. Only after I click an item with a `Validation` error do I see the associated red box.

I am using `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` and I can debug and see that the validation code is running at the correct time, but still the red boxes will not display. I even added code to re-fire the 'Property changed' events on the bound properties whenever the `TabItem` gains focus - but this still does not help. Here is an example of one of the `TextBox`es that is not showing the validation:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Margin="10,5,5,5" Width="150" MaxLength="5" Style="{StaticResource ServiceEntryTextBox}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="TexBox1BoundProperty" Converter="{StaticResource DoubleConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validation:StringRegexFormatValidation RegexPattern="^[0-9]{0,1}.{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}$" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Is there another piece I am missing?

Comment: [How to Implement Binding Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753962(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try placing your `TextBox` inside an `AdornerDecorator`? I need to dig out the source for this but I have seen issues before where controls inside a Tab control do not render the validation correctly.

e.g.

```
<AdornerDecorator>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Margin="10,5,5,5" Width="150" MaxLength="5" Style="{StaticResource ServiceEntryTextBox}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="TexBox1BoundProperty" Converter="{StaticResource DoubleConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validation:StringRegexFormatValidation RegexPattern="^[0-9]{0,1}.{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}$" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

**Further help for debugging**

I have also seen issues when binding directly to a `DependencyProperty`. The issue I saw was I was raising `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to trigger the validation to be processed (which worked fine in .NET 4.0) however since .NET 4.5 you cannot use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for triggering validation on a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Placing the TextBox inside an AdornerDecorator worked for me. Still, don't know why I had to.